# I want to display the QlistWidgets item in QlineEdit onclick of item

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit, qlistwidget

I have a QlistWidgets with some data in it and QlineEdit.
I want if QlistWidgets item is clicked it should show in QlineEdit.
Below is the screenshots

[image]

and this is my link to the my project
https://github.com/saurav389/Smart_Payroll_Management/blob/master/Department.py

I have tried in pyqt5 on windows

This is My code which add item from database

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('NewEmployee.db')
c = connection.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT Department FROM Department')
count = 0
for row in c.fetchall():
    item = self.listWidget_DepartView.item(count)
    raw = str(row).replace("('", "").replace("',)", "")
    item.setText(_translate("Dialog", raw))
    count = count + 1
    self.listWidget_DepartView.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QListWidget has a signal called [`itemClicked()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemClicked) that carries the item that you can use to get the associated text:

```
    # ...
    self.listWidget_DepartView.itemClicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
    # ...

def on_clicked(self, item):
    self.lineEdit_AddDepart.setText(item.text())
```

---

Another possible solution is to use the [clicked()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#clicked) signal from QAbstractItemView since QListWidget inherits from that class.

```
    # ...
    self.listWidget_DepartView.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
    # ...

def on_clicked(self, index):
    self.lineEdit_AddDepart.setText(index.data())
```

Comment: Hey after adding your suggested code.
when i clicked on item of Qlistwidget
it return an error as 'QModelIndex' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @boomyourcareer You are correct, I was wrong to signal, try again